# Know if the context menu is opened

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would need to know if the context menu has been opened for my JavaScript program.
I have to execute a function only when I see that the context menu is opened.

Could you help me?

Comment: Where is your "context menu open" event/ method?

Comment: Without code how can we make it happen?

Comment: This is covered [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/contextmenu)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function() {
    console.log('ya right');
});
```

The above snippet logs `ya right` when the user right clicks.